# Firewalling specific devices on LAN using a RV082 but have those device static IP transparent

Tags: cisco, firewall

I have a device with a static IP configured. This device is part of a small network. I have an old Cisco RV082 dual-WAN router that I would like to use as a firewall solely for this device to protect it from rest of the network (because I could not install a software firewall on the device.). Is possible to configure RV082 such that the static IP of this device is transparent to the rest of the network (at least transparent to those that follow the firewall rules)?

**Edit**: Is there a possibility to add some kind of firewall hardware for a specific device on the same subnet as rest of the network?

Comment: You need an actual firewall.

Comment: So there is no way to configure RV082 to be a firewall?

Comment: So something like Netgate SG-1000 can do I want? I'm not certain it wouldn't encounter the same problem as I'm encountering now, where outside of the firewall has the same IP subnet as inside of the firewall.

Comment: Questions about a consumer-grade device, such as that one, would be off-topic here. There are business-grade routers that can be set up transparently, but product or resource recommendations are off-topic on SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se].

Comment: I see. I apologize for going off-topic then. My main question is the possibility of implementing a firewall for a single device with the same subnet as rest of the network. I am unsure of the term(s) describing this type of implementation, hence, asking the question here. Moreover, I'm confused the difference between "an actual firewall" and a router with integrated firewall. Can you elaborate on your reply?

Comment: Routers route traffic between networks. There are some routers that have some firewall capability, often as a license upgrade, but they are still routers. A dedicated firewall probably has more features, and some can be configured as transparent so that the traffic simply passes through on the same network instead of being routed from one network to another network. There are devices that can do what you want, be we cannot recommend any. You may be able to get a recommendation on [hardwarerecs.se].

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and fine-tuning my questions on various forums, the answer is that I needed a Layer-2 or Transparent Firewall. This firewall can be integrated inline (or bump-in-the-wire). It'll shield device(s) behind the firewall from unwanted traffic but still allow the device(s) to be part of the same subnet as rest of the network.

Typical router-integrated firewall is not good enough for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use integrated routing and bridging with zone based firewall, though I haven’t done this before

Comment: That is a SOHO router that doesn't have that.